# Add code blocks to alternate image text

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, markdown, code-formatting

I often find the need to post an image in an answer to help summarize my point. I have used these before to demonstrate things such as CSS properties, as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16203271/1470950) answer. I added the code that the picture was displaying as an alternate text. I was thinking that it would be cool if I could somehow display this in the markdown format. It could be a command like

```
![code(alternatetext)][1]
```

Or it could be like code is formatted now

```
![    alternatetext][1]
```

I realize that there is probably an option to wrap them in backslashes, but this isn't as effective.

Comment: If you're putting source code in an image, you should rethink. What's wrong with writing _"`transition: <property> <duration> <type> <delay>`, for example `transition: all .5s ease-in-out 1s`"_

Comment: @Eric the picture is very clear and to the point

Comment: Also, even in [the given example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16203271/1470950) people who can actually see the image might still want to copy that text, or search bots might want to index it. And on mobile, the image might be shown much smaller. I agree with @Eric here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The alternate text there actually gets placed in the `alt` attribute for the image (which only gets displayed when the image cannot be rendered) and cannot be formatted with HTML. So no, there's no way to do this (or any other kind of formatting).